# Deploying qt3d project for android under windows

Tags: qt5

i am trying to deploy a test program on android with qt5 and qt3d under windows.
Building qt3d was a success, still libraries and sources needed to be copied manually into my Qt5 folder. It looks like that qt3d is working fine, the module is recognized as such.

Now I wanted to build one of those example projects inside the qt3d folder. To be more precise, I tried to build the qt3d teapot example.

```
C:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -std=gnu++0x -O2 -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_PRINTDIALOG -DQT_NO_XKBCOMMON -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_3D_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++ -I..\teapot -I..\..\..\include -I..\..\..\include\Qt3D -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtOpenGL -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore -I.moc\release_shared -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include -I. -o .obj\release_shared\teapotview.obj ..\teapot\teapotview.cpp
C:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -std=gnu++0x -O2 -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_PRINTDIALOG -DQT_NO_XKBCOMMON -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_3D_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++ -I..\teapot -I..\..\..\include -I..\..\..\include\Qt3D -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtOpenGL -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore -I.moc\release_shared -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include -I. -o .obj\release_shared\main.obj ..\teapot\main.cpp
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\bin\moc.exe -DQT_NO_PRINTDIALOG -DQT_NO_XKBCOMMON -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_3D_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++ -I..\teapot -I..\..\..\include -I..\..\..\include\Qt3D -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtOpenGL -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore -I.moc\release_shared -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include ..\teapot\teapotview.h -o .moc\release_shared\moc_teapotview.cpp
C:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -std=gnu++0x -O2 -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_PRINTDIALOG -DQT_NO_XKBCOMMON -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_3D_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++ -I..\teapot -I..\..\..\include -I..\..\..\include\Qt3D -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtOpenGL -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\include\QtCore -I.moc\release_shared -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a\include -IC:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include -I. -o .obj\release_shared\moc_teapotview.obj .moc\release_shared\moc_teapotview.cpp
C:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=C:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/ -Wl,-soname,libteapot.so -Wl,-rpath-link=C:/Qt/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/android_armv7/lib -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o \bin\libteapot.so .obj\release_shared\teapotview.obj .obj\release_shared\main.obj .obj\release_shared\moc_teapotview.obj   -LC:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a -LC:\Qt\android-ndk-r9b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib -LC:/Qt/qt-3d/lib -lQt53D -LC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/libs/armeabi-v7a -LC:\Qt\android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm//usr/lib -lgnustl_shared -lsupc++ -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc -lgcc -LC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\android_armv7\lib -lQt5OpenGL -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 
16:19:28: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
16:19:28: Elapsed time: 00:11.
```

Now I wanted to deploy that project for android(hitting that arrow button). Deploying to Android was not a success. No APK file was generated, it just fails.

```
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
16:22:02: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
16:22:02: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" INSTALL_ROOT="C:\Qt\qt-3d\examples\qt3d\teapot\android" install
Die Syntax fr den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datentr„gerbezeichnung ist falsch.
makefile:1908: recipe for target 'install_target' failed
mingw32-make: *** [install_target] Error 1
16:22:04: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project teapot (kit: Android for arm (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.1.1)-Qt 5.1.1 for Android armv7)
When executing step 'Copy application data'
16:22:04: Elapsed time: 00:05
```

So wheres the problem? Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the Qt3D example pro file where it includes the pri. The way I get examples to build on Android and deploy is by creating a new Quick2 project and simply copy the qml and other resources into the new project qml folder. Then if you use assets everything is copied to the APK for you. If you want faster loading add a resource file to the project and add all the existing files and in main.cpp change to using the qrc: prefix to pick up the entry point qml file. Good luck!